# regex npp - search string must be followed by specific chars, but not include those chars

Tags: regex, notepad++

In the line below, I need to these two lines into one single line by replacing the newline and empty space with nothing.

`Provisioned Links               : 2/14,    2/24,    7/10,    7/12,

                                    7/25,    7/31,    7/32`

Therefore I have this regex (in Notepad++):

```
(\r\n|\n)\s+[0-9]\/[0-9]*
```

Problem: the match includes the 7/25 - I need it to look for the `#/##` but not include it.

If I use this [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) pattern:

```
(\r\n|\n)\s+(q=[0-9]\/[0-9])*
```

all lines beginning with newline + spaces are matched, whether or not they end with `#/##`.

What am I doing wrong?

<kbd>[**regex101 fiddle to play with**](https://regex101.com/r/PbGPjx/1)</kbd>

Comment: Note: You've a typo in your lookahead. A positive lookahead construction begins with `(?=` and all other clusters except a capturing group `(...)` begins with a question mark `?` immediately after opening parenthesis `(`. Also they're not quantifiable.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add an explicit sample, for example the one you use in regex101 AND the attended output. It's not clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful:

- You should correct the way you constructed the lookahead: `(?=....)`
- Lookarounds are not quantifiable.

so what you need really is `[\r\n]\s+(?=[0-9]\/[0-9]*)`.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbGPjx/2)

Answer (score 0):

To normalize whitespace, why not simply replace "comma with additional space after it" with "comma plus one tab character" ?

You don't need that complicated pattern at all, because `\s` matches spaces, newlines, and tabs all at the same time:

Pattern:  `,\s*`

Replacement string:  `,\t`

https://regex101.com/r/T0QJnq/1